# Issue using Insights Edge API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get some insights data using Insights Edge API, but running into permissions issue:

Here is the code I am using:

```
string applicationId = "";
string applicationSecret = "";
string accountId = "";

System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string accessToken = client.DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + applicationId + "&client_secret=" + applicationSecret + "&grant_type=client_credentials").Replace("access_token=","");
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/act_"+accountId+"/insights?access_token=" + accessToken);
System.Net.WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
using(System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

I am getting the following JSON back:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 10
   }
}
```

Application in question was created under the same Facebook account as the ad account. What do I need to check in account/application settings to see if I have all the correct permissions to access Ad Insights API? The code will need to run in the service that doesn't require user intervention, is application access token the right way to access ad insight data in this case?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/overview#access_token

Comment: Yeah it looks like you're trying to use an App Access Token to make the call instead of the user access token from the correct user

Comment: thanks CBroe, using instructions you have linked to worked for getting a long lived access token for the app.